# Несколько аббревиатур рядом

Tags: аббревиатура

Если рядом несколько аббревиатур, почему все пишется слитно?... НИИСХ, например, научно-исследовательский институт сельского хозяйства.

Comment: У вас же одна аббревиатура, а не несколько.

Comment: Почему пишется слитно, мой вопрос....  ГБУЗРК не пишется слитно, например....

Comment: Потому что изъять нельзя, входит в название. И нет аббревиатуры СХ.

Comment: Здесь имеет место расширение аббревиатуры, а не соединение двух.

Comment: Есть правило?...

Comment: Не думаю. Здесь просто элементарная логика. Должна существовать вторая аббревиатура... Мы не можем делать аббревиатуру из чего попало. Во втором случае указывается место. Там изъятие не критично для смысла.